# Magento store authentication and get API key

Tags: php, magento

I am newbie in magento. I want to do following things :

How to do magento store authentication to access store from my website.
Is there anything I have to implement OAuth or something else ?

I would like to do like, when any Magento store admin visits my website and clicks on get api key button then it should first authenticate with his store and I should get API key of that Magento store to access their store.

How to do this?

Comment: anyone magento expert here ?

Comment: http://docs.shopify.com/support/other/general-information/finding-magento-api-credentials

Answer (score 0):

I had already faced with this issue. To do magento authentication you can use magento SOAP or magento REST. Magento REST is more preferable, imho, and seems more suitable for your goals, but it needs 3-way Oauh 1.0a authentication.You can find all details here [Official doc](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/introduction.html)